# Inserting data into a static Hive partition using Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have trouble figuring out how to insert data into a static partition of a Hive table using Spark SQL. I can use code like this to write into dynamic partitions:

```
df.write.partitionBy("key").insertInto("my_table")
```

However, I can't figure out how to insert the data into a static partition. That means, I want to define the partition where the entire DataFrame should be written without the need to add the column to the DataFrame.

I see static partitioning mentioned in the 
[InsertIntoHiveTable](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/hive/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/execution/InsertIntoHiveTable.scala#L164) class, so I guess it is supported. Is there a public API to do what I want?

Comment: were you able to find any API similar to writing into Dynamic partition?

Comment: No, I was not able to find anything and ended up registering the RRD as a temporary table and running SQL INSERT from that. However a lot of the Hive code has been rewritten in Spark 2.0 so it might be possible now.

Comment: did this work for you, Iam unable to doe partition by with insertinto

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
DataFrame tableMeta = sqlContext.sql(String.format("DESCRIBE FORMATTED %s", tableName));
String location = tableMeta.filter("result LIKE 'Location:%'").first().getString(0);
```

and use regex to get your table partition. Once you get the table location, you can easily construct the partition location like

```
String partitionLocation = location + "/" + partitionKey
```

(partitionKey is something like dt=20160329/hr=21)

Then, you can write to that path

```
df.write.parquet(partitionLocation)
```

(in my case when I build the dataframe, I do not include the partition columns in. Not sure if there is any error when partition columns are included)

Comment: I think registering the DataFrame as a temporary table and then running Hive SQL that inserts data from there to a particular partition is a better solution than this (it's less fragile), but I was wondering specifically about native support for this in Spark.

Comment: Agree with running HiveSQL to insert data. I'm looking for the native support for this as well, but could not find it any where.